# Big number arithmetic using LLVM (from Haskell)

Tags: haskell, llvm, gmp, integer-arithmetic

An answer to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595312/getting-ghc-to-produce-add-with-carry-adc-instructions) indicated that Haskell represents [`plusWord2#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:plusWord2-35-) as [`llvm.uadd.with.overflow`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-uadd-with-overflow-intrinsics). I'm looking to do long addition with carry, like how the x86 ADC instruction works. This instruction not only adds it's two arguments, but also adds the contents of the carry bit.

One can then add long numbers like the following:

```
ADD x1 y1
ADC x2 y2
ADC x3 y3
...
```

Resulting in one instruction per word (disregarding any surrounding moves etc required).

I looked at the GMP library, and how it did long addition itself, in its generic C code. Here's an excerpt from `mpn/generic/add_n.c`

```
sl = ul + vl;
cy1 = sl < ul;
rl = sl + cy;
cy2 = rl < sl;
cy = cy1 | cy2;
```

Note it saves the carry bits from both the original addition and the addition of the carry bit. Only one of these operations can carry, so or'ing the carries afterwards is sufficient.

Obviously GMP has specific assembly code for particular platforms, but I thought the generic code would be a good basis, as it would presumably be written to compile to reasonable code. The `plusWord2#` primitive operation means I don't need to do silly comparisons to get the carry bit, so I implemented the GMP generic code like the following in Haskell:

```
addWithCarry :: Word# -> Word# -> Word# -> (# Word#, Word# #)
addWithCarry x y c =
  let 
    (# c1, r1 #) = plusWord2# x y
    (# c2, r2 #) = plusWord2# r1 c
  in
    (# or# c1 c2, r2 #)
```

Unfortunately this results in x86 code that saves the carry bit into a register before then adding the carry bit on it's own, as well as adding the two numbers, resulting in three or four instructions per word instead of one.

So what I'm wondering is how I can combine `llvm.uadd.with.overflow` to create a chain of ADC instructions on x86 to implement multi-precision arithmetic. If I got LLVM code that produced efficient long addition I was hoping I could then convert it back into Haskell primitive ops to produce the efficient addition directly from Haskell code.

**Notes:**

I could of course use Haskell's FFI to call inline assembly or GMP, but that would stop inlining and I suspect be relatively slow as compared to inlined code for small (i.e. <=256 bit) operands.

I've found that 'clang' has [`__builtin_addc`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#multiprecision-arithmetic-builtins), a form of three argument addition that takes not only two numbers but a carry bit, but GHC doesn't compile via clang, so I don't see how this is useful.

Comment: You could try to implement your function as a primop. Newer versions of ghc support the [`foreign import prim`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface#Foreign_PrimOps) syntax. From C-- you can call whichever assembly instructions you need to hyper-optimize your code, and you get the benefit of your foreign function being a first class haskell function. Of course, the downside is this requires knowing a significant amount about the GHC RTS.

Comment: @user2407038: the issue with current foreign primops is that they're never inlined.

Comment: See if you can get clang to generate a series of ADCs with `__builtin_addc` and if so have it output the intermediate LLVM code. Then see if you can get GHC to generate sufficiently similar LLVM code. (The NCG is just not smart enough about using the condition register for this.)

Comment: I gather that the GMP has been carefully optimised; I would be very wary of thinking you can do better, even if you save a JSR and RTN.

Comment: GMP implements the math with SSE & will implement individual code for different CPUs of the same assembly language. See https://github.com/SaberMod/gnu-gmp/tree/6.0.0/mpn/x86_64

Answer (score 1):

The correct thing to do here is to make sure that your Haskell frontend represents your carrying arithmetic in LLVM's IR using the same patterns formed by Clang when using its __builtin_addc.

However, don't expect this to produce good code with LLVM today. See http://llvm.org/PR20748 which documents the absolutely horrible code we currently generate on x86 for trivial patterns like this. But once that bug is fixed, you should get the generated code you desire.